# Where should I ask my question about partition types and performance?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation, stack-exchange, asking-questions

I have a question about partition types and their performance for an external HDD.

So is there any Stack Exchange site in which I could ask this question?

I have searched on the Internet, but I couldn't find my answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) could help you.

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking

Relevant tags to start with could be [`external-hard-drive`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-hard-drive) and [`partitioning`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/partitioning).

Good chance the question is already asked there too, so make sure you search their site before accidentally posting a duplicate.